# fftw very inefficient when running multiple simultaneous processes

Tags: c++, fftw

I am finding that fftw becomes very inefficient when it is running simultaneously in many (say 8+) different processes, even when I have many cores (20) on my machine. This is very surprising as I am able to parallelize many other cpu-intensive tasks in this very simple way. But fftw struggles.

Here's the output of a C++ test program I created:

```
magland@jm3:~/dev/fftw_load_test$ ./fftw_load_test.js --num_processes=1 --task=fftw
Calling: bin/fftw_load_test --task=fftw
Creating plan...
Running fftw load test for M,N=4,40000000
Elapsed time (sec) for M,N=4,40000000 (1.20901e+7 nums per sec): 13.234
```

Contrast that when running the same program simply launched in 6 separate processes!

```
Running fftw load test for M,N=4,40000000
Running fftw load test for M,N=4,40000000
Running fftw load test for M,N=4,40000000
Running fftw load test for M,N=4,40000000
Running fftw load test for M,N=4,40000000
Running fftw load test for M,N=4,40000000
Elapsed time (sec) for M,N=4,40000000 (1.10079e+7 nums per sec): 14.535
Elapsed time (sec) for M,N=4,40000000 (1.02328e+7 nums per sec): 15.636
Elapsed time (sec) for M,N=4,40000000 (1.01183e+7 nums per sec): 15.813
Elapsed time (sec) for M,N=4,40000000 (6.55845e+6 nums per sec): 24.396
Elapsed time (sec) for M,N=4,40000000 (6.16642e+6 nums per sec): 25.947
Elapsed time (sec) for M,N=4,40000000 (6.11084e+6 nums per sec): 26.183
```

This is the type of thing I keep finding. It took me quite a long time to isolate to such a simple example since I did not suspect there could be such a basic limitation with FFTW.

This is how I am invoking the fftw:

```
typedef long long bigint;

struct Fftw_runner {
    Fftw_runner() {

    }

    ~Fftw_runner() {
        fftw_free(data_in);
        fftw_free(data_out);
    }
    void init(bigint M_in,bigint N_in,QString task_in) {
        M=M_in;
        N=N_in;
        MN=M*N;
        task=task_in;

        data_in = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * MN);
        data_out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * MN);

        int rank = 1;
        int n[] = { (int)N };
        int howmany = M;
        int* inembed = n;
        int istride = M;
        int idist = 1;
        int* onembed = n;
        int ostride = M;
        int odist = 1;
        unsigned flags = FFTW_ESTIMATE;
        if (task=="fftw") {
            qDebug() << "Creating plan...";
            p_fft = fftw_plan_many_dft(rank,n,howmany,data_in,inembed,istride,idist,data_out,onembed,ostride,odist,FFTW_FORWARD,flags);
        }

    }
    void apply() {
        if (task=="fftw") {
            for (bigint i=0; i<MN; i++) {
                data_in[i][0]=0;
                data_in[i][1]=0;
            }
            //set input data
            //fft
            fftw_execute(p_fft);
            //multiply by kernel
        }
        else if (task=="flops") {
            double sum=0;
            for (bigint n=0; n<N; n++) {
                for (bigint m=0; m<M; m++) {
                    sum+=m*n;
                }
            }
            printf("Print the result to force computation: %g\n",sum);
        }
    }

    bigint M;
    bigint N,MN;
    QString task;
    fftw_complex* data_in=0;
    fftw_complex* data_out=0;
    fftw_plan p_fft;
};
```

As you can see, the above program can also test simple floating-point operations, so I tested that as well and no interference between processes.

If this is true, it is a very serious performance limitation to my application where I need to be running dozens of simultaneous processes. Pondering writing my own 1D fft in the simple case of N being a power of 2. Shouldn't be that hard, right?

Comment: how much cache does 1 fftw use?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik if that is the issue is there an easy way to limit the cache use of each process?

Comment: @AlexanderMorley if somehow `fftw_execute(p_fft);` uses all cores, it can have better performance and less latency per fftw(with a preemptive scheduling between processes)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik. In my application I need a single thread per process.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I don't know how much cache 1 fftw uses, how could I find out?

Comment: Are you creating an FFT plan every time you need to calculate an FFT ? If so then don't do that ! Cache the plan and re-use it.

Comment: Also, if you cache the plan like @PaulR noted, and you are using it many times, you can do better than `FFTW_ESTIMATE`. It's been a while since I used fftw but I remember there being an option just above that which seemed to give decent speed FFTs without taking too long to create the plan

Comment: I only create the plan once... per process. There's no way to share a plan between processes. Also, the timing is just for the fftw_exec part.

Comment: @magland what I meant by the FFTW_ESTIMATE comment is that you can change that which will cause creating the plan to take longer, but the fftw_exec should be faster. So if you execute one plan enough times, it is worth the investment. If you don't execute it enough times... an estimate is good enough.

Comment: @RyanP, what you say makes sense. But I don't think it is related to the problem I am reporting.